# Tree structure which sorts but retains original order of elements

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree

I'm searching for a tree structure (like a binary tree) with the following qualities:

- The elements in the tree can be traversed in order
- The original order of elements can be retrieved
- It can do the above efficiently (in O(n log n) time if possible)

I'm pretty certain I came across such a type of (binary?) tree a while ago, but searches on Google and Wikipedia are turning up nothing. Such a structure could be significant for a function I'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) (Java) or [LinkedTreeMap](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap.java) (Java implementation linked).

Comment: That's one way to do it, but IIRC, the structure I encountered accomplished the goal algorithmically without the need for extra storage.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to find it. It's called a [Cartesian Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_tree).